# No scroll bar in popup window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added these css to a web page and opened it as a popup with js from another page. But the scroll bar is not appearing in the popup (but it appears in web pages other than a popup).

**css:**

```
html{
    overflow: hidden;    
}
body{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**js:**

```
window.open(url, 'newwindow', 'width=1800, height=1600, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes').focus();
```

Anybody knows a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

*note: I'm unable to create a jsfiddle because I can't apply css to the opened window there*

Answer (score 0):

If there is a `overflow: hidden` on the html element, it won't display what is outside of the window and that's why there are no scrollbars.

Just remove it and it should work fine.

Comment: But a scroll bar is added to the body with the css. The scroll should be there on the body. This works in web pages other than popups.